# How can I access a subdomain through ngrok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ngrok

I have a rails site with an "api" subdomain. The routes on my local machine look like this:

```
http://mysite.dev         #<-- normal web stuff
http://api.mysite.dev     #<-- my api
```

How can I map these two subdomains? This is my ngrok config file, but the api endpoint seems to point to the base domain.

```
tunnels:
web:
    subdomain: "my-project"
    proto:
        http: mysite.dev:5000
api:
    subdomain: "api.my-project"
    proto:
        http: api.mysite.dev:5000
```

Comment: I don't think it would be possible without avoiding some updates to your code. As the resulting ngrok URL would be `api.my-project.ngrok.com` Would be helpful if you can share your routes file, or share how you are routing requests based on the subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using Constraints in your routes, I would suggest a constraint class such as the following:

```
class APIConstraint

  def matches?(request)
     # I would extract the hard coded domains out into some config
     # file, but you get the idea..
     request.host == "ngrok.com" ? request.subdomain.include?("api") : request.subdomain == "api"
  end

end
```

And then in your `routes.rb`

```
namespace :api do
  constraints APIConstraint.new do
    resources :some_resource
  end
end
```