# Detect ngrok from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ngrok

I am using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) in order to test my Rails application integration with PayPal.

Since my application works with subdomains, I would like to detect when call is made from ngrok so I can apply a different behaviour.

Is there any way to configure ngrok to pass some information so I can detect the call comes from there? Or any other way to know that ngrok stands behind the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your controller, you could check the `request.host`, which would have something related to `ngrok` somewhere there.

Or look at [this older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637457/how-can-i-access-a-subdomain-through-ngrok) which uses a route constraint.

Comment: Thanks, simple and true!!