# ngrok + stripe webhook for multi-tenant application (subdomains)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant application I am currently testing. When a user signs up for an account, a subdomain is created for the account. Upon successful creation, this process happens:

**Accounts Controller**

```
def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      sign_in(@account.owner)
      flash[:notice] = "Your account has been created."
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Sorry, your account could not be created."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The user is redirected to their account with the url now being subdomain.url.com

The above works great with lvh.me in development, but when I use ngrok for testing - using to test stripe webooks - my ngrok tunnel address conflicts with the subdomain that is being set.

My stripe webook looks something like this:
https://3abg89zc.ngrok.io/webhooks/stripe

When the account is created, my url goes to: https://subdomain.ngrok.io/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer here might work:
[How can I access a subdomain through ngrok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637457/how-can-i-access-a-subdomain-through-ngrok)

However, I found it easier to test in a live environment by using heroku.